# Resolve promises created within Array.map on a timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, es6-promise

I'm trying to resolve an array of promises using a timeout to avoid rate limit exceptions on API requests. However, I'm still hitting the rate limit, as the timeout doesn't seem to be working.

Not really sure how to make this work.

```js
router.route("/").put(async (req, res) => {
  const { apiKey: access_token, course, assignments } = req.body;
  try {
    const returnedIds = [];
    const promises = await assignments.map((assignment) => {
      return axios({
        method: "PUT",
        url: `https://url.to.api/api/v1/courses/${course}/assignments/${assignment.id}`,
        params: {
          access_token,
        },
        data: {
          assignment: {
            points_possible: assignment.points_possible,
          },
        },
      });
    });
    const promiseResolution = function() {
      Promise.all([...promises]).then((values) => {
        values.forEach((_, index) => {
          returnedIds.push(assignments[index].id);
        });
        res.status(201).json({
          returnedIds,
        });
      });
    };
    setTimeout(promiseResolution, 5000);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(401);
  }
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to separate making each request by 5 seconds? I.e. make the first request, wait 5 seconds, make the second request, wait 5 seconds, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to put some time between API calls this should do.

```
router.route("/").put(async (req, res) => {
    const { apiKey, course, assignments } = req.body;
    try {
        const returnedIds = [];
        for (const assignment of assignments) {
            returnedIds.push(await loadID(apiKey, course, assignment));
            await wait(5000);
        }
        res.status(201).json({ returnedIds })

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(401);
    }
});

function wait(duration) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
}

function loadID(apiKey, course, assignment) {
    // Makes the request, parses out the stuff you want from the response...
}
```

I would caution against using `Promise.all` since you probably want to check the result of each request before making the next one. For example, if the third request gets rate limited, you probably shouldn't bother making further requests.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Promise.all` will fire all promises at once, so your `setTimeout` is just set a timeout for all promises not individual promise as well.
You should try to make delay for each promise:

```
const promises = await assignments.map((assignment) => {
      // some delay function

      return axios({
        method: "PUT",
        url: `https://url.to.api/api/v1/courses/${course}/assignments/${assignment.id}`,
        params: {
          access_token,
        },
        data: {
          assignment: {
            points_possible: assignment.points_possible,
          },
        },
      });
    });
```

You can try this: (It's React but you should only focus on fetchData function) and see the logs:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-feynman-ql833?file=/src/App.js